# Javascript: How to redirect a user to the appstore on iOS 9

Tags: javascript, safari, ios9

On iOS 8 and earlier, when a user clicks the "Play Now" button on our website, we are loading our game.html file which will check if the user is on iOS and if so will forward them to the appstore:

```
var isIOS = ua.indexOf("ipad") > -1 || ua.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || ua.indexOf("ipod") > -1;

if (isIOS)
{
    alert('We are forwarding you to the appstore now.');
    window.top.location = iosUrl;

    return;
}
```

However this does not work on iOS 9 anymore. I noticed that the redirect will work if I replace iosUrl with a generic URL like "http://www.google.de", however any URLs to "https://itunes.apple.com" or "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com" will not open. What is the reason and how can I recreate the same behavior on iOS 9?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: No, I gave up on the issue. Do you have the same problem? I was even trying to set up a redirect in php on another website that forwards to iTunes. But what happens is that for a short moment the URL to the redirect page is shown in Safari and when it notices that it redirects to iTunes it reverts the URL back to the original page.

Comment: Just so you know, we added an additional HTML popup "We are forwarding you to the appstore now.". and on that click listener we open the URL. Seems to work well.